# APGL version of iText on Github

Tags: itext

I have created a project using APGL version of iText. Now, I want to share this code in the Github account of mine. But, I donot know what should I do so that not breaking the rule. May you help me with clear instruction?

If licence.txt is enough, do you have a sample licences.txt?

Note: I am using  Java verions of iText

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing and not about a specific technical problem. Moreover, it's a duplicate of a question that was answered on the iText mailing-list: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/66461

Answer (score 1):

Copy/paste from the [iText mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/66461) where the exact same question was posted:

> The source code headers of your own code should mention the AGPL 
>   (similar to what is present in the iText source code headers, but with
>   references to your own project).
>
> As for the licenses.txt: it is important that people downloading your 
>   source code know that they are also using iText, so a licenses.txt
>   with  a reference to the iText web site http://itextpdf.com and
>   especially  where to find the iText code is sufficient, for instance a
>   link to  https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/

Please avoid cross-posting questions on different forums. Pick the forum you like most and stick to it.

Comment: Is that github repository up to date? It claims the last change to have happened 7 months ago. ..

Comment: I'll ask "our" Michaël. It seems like the most recent release wasn't uploaded to Github.

Comment: @mkl That repository is now officially up to date, since we moved from svn (SourceForge) to git (GitHub) earlier this year. We actually commit to the develop branch on an internal GitLab server; Jenkins builds and tests, and if the build is ok, the changes get pushed to GitHub on a daily basis. We also accept (and have already accepted) pull requests.